# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array in my code

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-listfragment

I have a login page. If the user successfully logs in, a new `Activity` should be started containing a `ListFragment` that contains user's private projects. I loop through all the project titles (from the json result I get) and store it in an array. And then inflate the ListFragment with the details(the project titles).As soon as the user clicks submit, `ProjectListActivity.java` is called. But I am getting the error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

What am I doing wrong here?

**private_projects_list.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/privateProjectsContainer">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.amangrover.finalapp1.ProjectListFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**ProjectListActivity.java:**

```
public class ProjectListActivity extends Activity {
private final static String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private final static String TAG_ANIM_ARRAY_ID = "animation_array";
private final static String TAG_PROJECTS = "projects";
private final static String TAG_ID = "id";

JSONArray projects = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new HttpGetHandler().execute();
    setContentView(R.layout.private_project_list);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.privateProjectsContainer, new ProjectListFragment());
    ft.commit();
}

private class HttpGetHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String jsonUrl = "some url";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(jsonUrl);
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = MainActivity.httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream content = httpEntity.getContent();
            String result = convertToString(content);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            projects = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_PROJECTS);
            ProjectListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        ArrayList<String> projectTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<String> imageId = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<String> playId = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(int i=0; i<projects.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject p = projects.getJSONObject(i);
                            String title = p.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                            String id = p.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String array_anim_id = p.getString(TAG_ANIM_ARRAY_ID);
                            String imgId = array_anim_id.substring(0, 4);
                            projectTitle.add(title);
                            imageId.add(imgId);
                            playId.add(id);
                        }
                        String[] arrProjectTitle = new String[projectTitle.size()];
                        String[] arrImageId = new String[imageId.size()];
                        final String[] pid = new String[playId.size()];
                        for(int i = 0; i<projectTitle.size(); i++)
                            arrProjectTitle[i] = projectTitle.get(i);
                        for(int j = 0; j<imageId.size(); j++)
                            arrImageId[j] = imageId.get(j);
                        for(int k = 0; k<playId.size(); k++)
                            pid[k] = playId.get(k);

                        /*Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putStringArray("projectTitle", arrProjectTitle);
                        b.putStringArray("projectId", pid);
                        b.putStringArray("imageId", arrImageId);*/
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putStringArray("projectTitle", arrProjectTitle);
                        ProjectListFragment fragment = new ProjectListFragment();
                        fragment.setArguments(b);
                    }catch(Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String convertToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
            result += line;

        }
        inputStream.close();
        return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I have to make a GET call to that `some url` if the user is logged in. So I have to do with `AsyncTask`. Although I checked with the debugger, I am getting the data with the json url, but the error is in the code for the Fragment class:

**ProjectListFragment.java:**

```
public class ProjectListFragment extends ListFragment{
String[] projectTitle;
String[] projectImage;

CustomAdapter adapter;

private List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    /*Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    projectTitle = args.getStringArray("projectTitle");
    projectImage = args.getStringArray("imageId");*/

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle!=null){
        projectTitle = bundle.getStringArray("projectTitle");
    }

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for(int i=0; i<projectTitle.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(projectTitle[i], 0);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error in the for loop.

Comment: Why you added `Fragment` manually in layout file?

Comment: Also why your are calling `runOnUiThread(...)` in `Background(...)` ?

Comment: you should load you fragment after getting the response from web services

Comment: Earlier I wasn't using `runOnUIThread` , and I was getting `NetworkOnMainThread Exception`

Comment: Actually I am using the same `Fragment` to inflate public projects in the `MainActivity` and I want to use the same Fragment to inflate with different  data.

Comment: @Madhu So should I load the fragment in some other Life Activity method? Like onPause?

Comment: you do not even understand what you are doing ... `ft.add(R.id.privateProjectsContainer, new ProjectListFragment()).commit()` ... you showing the fragment **without any arguments** ... so why are you expecting to get 'em "on the other side"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("projectTitle", arrProjectTitle);
    ProjectListFragment fragment = new ProjectListFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(b);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.privateProjectsContainer, fragment);
    ft.commit();


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/privateProjectsContainer">

</FrameLayout>
```

Better you do the fragment transaction using code. and replace the container layout using your fragment. In your case you are not passing that arguments to the newly created frgament

Answer (score 0):

`jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_PROJECTS);` - returns null.
 There of in this line:

```
for(int i=0; i<projects.length(); i++) {
```

You get `NullPointerException`
to solve this problem do next:

```
if(projects != null){
    ProjectListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {/*Code here*/});
}
```